# Query MIN() SUBSTR() in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table "produit" in SQLite and I want to get the min but not in rows of table by subtring "Code", this is my query:

```
select MIN (substr(Code_produit,1,charindex('-',Code,1))+1)
from produit
where (substr(Code,1,charindex('-',Code_produit,1)) + 1)
      not in (select (substr(Code,1,charindex('-',Code_produit,1))) from produit)
```

ex: my Rows data "Code" are like this "PRD-1"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *But I want to query the minimum that doesn't existe in following data, in this exemple it must be 2*, Please provide the table schema, some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: i have the following data:
Column Code

PRD-13
PRDF-4
ADQ-1
ASFS-77
AGXX-9
AMXX-14
AXX-17

 
I want to query the minimum of the second party (after -) that doesn't existe in following data, in this exemple it must be 2
 
I make one but it doesn't work

select MIN (substr(Code,charindex('_',Code)+1)+1) from produit where (substr(Code,charindex('_',Code)+1) + 1) not in (select (substr(Code,charindex('_',Code)+1)) from produit)

Comment: From where this 2 came from?

Comment: You description is incomprehensible. SQLite has not function `charindex`. Why are there two columns `Code` and `Code_produit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will extract all numbers from the codes:

```
SELECT CAST(substr(code, instr(code, '-') + 1) AS INTEGER)
FROM produit
```

(The extracted substring is explicitly converted into an integer because strings and numbers would not compare correctly.)

This query can the be used to find your value:

```
WITH numbers(n)
AS (SELECT CAST(substr(code, instr(code, '-') + 1) AS INTEGER)
    FROM produit)
SELECT MIN(n + 1)
FROM numbers
WHERE n + 1 NOT IN numbers
```

If you don't yet have SQLite [3.8.3](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3.html), you cannot use [common table expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), so you have to either create a view for `numbers`, or insert it into the query explicitly:

```
SELECT MIN(n + 1)
FROM (SELECT CAST(substr(code, instr(code, '-') + 1) AS INTEGER) AS n
      FROM produit)
WHERE n + 1 NOT IN (SELECT CAST(substr(code, instr(code, '-') + 1) AS INTEGER)
                    FROM produit)
```